# EventHub Trigger Function get EventHub name form Application Setttings

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

Why does EventHub Trigger written in C# (not C# Script) take in some values from the application setting but not everything?

I have set up an event hub trigger function like so,

```
[FunctionName("MyFristTriggerFunction")]
public static void MyFristTriggerFunction(
    [EventHubTrigger("MyEventHub", Connection = @"EventHubConnectionString")] EventData[] events
    ILogger log)
{
    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    foreach (EventData eventData in events)
    {
        try
        {
            string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count);

            log.LogInformation($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {messageBody}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // We need to keep processing the rest of the batch - capture this exception and continue.
            // Also, consider capturing details of the message that failed processing so it can be processed again later.
            exceptions.Add(e);
        }
    }
    // Once processing of the batch is complete, if any messages in the batch failed processing throw an exception so that there is a record of the failure.

    if (exceptions.Count > 1)
        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);

    if (exceptions.Count == 1)
        throw exceptions.Single();
}
```

This works great if I pass in the string value - **MyEventHub**. However what I would like to do is pass in the name of the event hub as a variable that could be used from the Application settings, similar to the **EventHubConnectionString**. If I change the declaration,

```
public static void MyFristTriggerFunction(
    [EventHubTrigger(@"EventHubAppSettings", Connection = @"EventHubConnectionString")] EventData[] events
    ILogger log)
{
```

I get an error that the actual event hub - "EventHubAppSettings" could not be found. Is this something that has to be hard coded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can specify eventHubName as follows and have that property "evenHubName" configured in appsettings

```
[FunctionName("MyFristTriggerFunction")]
public static void MyFristTriggerFunction(
    [EventHubTrigger("%eventHubName%", Connection = @"EventHubConnectionString")] EventData[] events
    ILogger log)
{
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#trigger---configuration

> path  EventHubName    The name of the event hub. Can be referenced via app
>   settings %eventHubName%

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked using %eventHubName% but the connection has to be using @"EventHubConnectionString". So random one has to be using % and the other has to use @. Confusing, but it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes..That's true about randomness but that is what documentation is saying :)